# Which kind of data suitable for Convolution Neural Network

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorboard, tensorflow-serving

I'm searching dataset at websit [Machine Learning repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html?format=&task=cla&att=&area=&numAtt=&numIns=&type=&sort=nameUp&view=table).
I would like to find some specific kinds of dataset, which can be trained with convolution neural network. Actually, I have not much experience with this.
Could you let me know which kind of dataset on the link above I can used for **CNN** ?

It would be better for me if the kind of dataset is not big, because I used Tensorflow CPU

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

If you're a beginner in convolutional neural netwroks I would suggest you to use the [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). It is a database of handwritten digits images. It is a small and relatively simple dataset, ideal for beginners. And here's a very good [tutorial](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html) on how to apply neural network techniques on this dataset.

Comment: @ Harsh Wardhan: Thanks for your advice. I already know MNIST, but I would like to find other kinds of Dataset to apply CNN, but I don't know which kind of them will be suitable for my require. Because I think MNIST is too simple.

Comment: In that case you should explicitly state what exactly is your requirement. How do you expect people to guess what's your requirement?